# Error en Jason Verifying Email Hubs Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services

I installed HubsCloud in my AWS, but when trying to enter ADMIN, it sends the link and when trying to enter I get the following error:
verify
Error Verifying Email
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I await your answers
Thanks

[Error Verifying Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uFx0.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  There isn't much information from your post as to what the problem could be.  Did you follow the instructions @ https://hubs.mozilla.com/docs/hubs-cloud-aws-quick-start.html?  Incidentally, this seems more of a Hubscloud support question rather than a programming one.

Comment: I come to this group because in git and mozilla support no one gives an answer.
The question is clear for someone who has run into that error.
But if you need more info, I will gladly supply it.
Thanks

Comment: did you follow the instructions?   Your account configuration admin should be an email address w/ no capitals.  I don't use hubscloud (first time I've even heard that Mozilla released this..)